# How to restore cropped tilted labels?

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

I have this beutiful picture:
[image]

Created by this code:

```
  melt(mat_reordered) %>% ggplot(., aes(x=Var1, y=Var2)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = value)) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = value)) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "red") +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank(),
        axis.title=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=-0.2))
```

Everything is fine except for the angled x labels. How can I show them uncropped? Or how can I improve them other way?

Comment: Try with `hjust = 0`.

Comment: ^ The reason `hjust = 0` should work better is that the margins are calculated to fit the width of the labels, and in this case with `hjust = -0.2` you have put 20% of the text below the baseline. If you wanted to keep that alignment, you'd have to manually add more margin, e.g. with ` +  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1,1,10,1), "lines"))` and adjusting the `10` to taste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments `hjust=` and `vjust=` are positioning values for `element_text()`, but they always work *relative to the text position and angle*.  This means that when you angle the text by 90 degrees (so the text reads from down to top), positive values of `vjust` move text "left" and negative values move it "right".  Similarly, positive values of `hjust` move text *"up"* and negative values move it *"down"*.

In OP's case, the `hjust=-0.2` argument positions the axis text such that it would extend var to the bottom of the plot and... beyond a bit (negative values in `hjust` and `vjust` do weird things).  This is why it's definitely going to be clipped here.

To prevent clipping the text at the bottom, you would want it justified so that the text is aligned with the x axis.  Do this via `element_text(hjust=1)`.

Here's an example with `mtcars`:

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=rownames(mtcars), y=rownames(mtcars))) +
  geom_point() + theme_classic()

p + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, hjust=-0.2, vjust=0.5))
```

[image]

The text does not clip like yours, but the `-0.2` value makes the text clip into the axis title a bit.  With `hjust=0` the text aligns on the "bottom" next to the title, but not against the axis.  Here's what happens when `hjust` is set to `1`:

```
p + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, hjust=1, vjust=0.5))
```

[image]

Much better!  If you're still getting clipping, then you can play with the `margin` settings for the `axis.text.x` element:

```
p + theme(
      axis.text.x = element_text(
        angle=90, hjust=-0.2, vjust=0.5,
        margin=margin(b=50, unit='pt')
      )
    )
```

[image]

You might also need to adjust the margin of the axis title.  You can do that the same way or use any combination of `hjust` and `margin` for the axis text and/or title:

```
p + theme(
      axis.text.x = element_text(
        angle=90, hjust=-0.2, vjust=0.5,
        margin=margin(b=50, unit='pt')),
      axis.title.x = element_text(
        margin=margin(b=20, unit='pt'))
)
```

[image]